# I configured HP ILO, now I get hponcfg errors

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

Just installed I-Lo a few days back to one of my servers (Proliant DL380 G7).

Lights-Out Online Configuration Utility picked up a DHCP based IP address and I changed it to static.

Lights-Out said it would have to reset a couple of things and may become non-responsive for a couple minutes. I waited but it popped up an error that said:

"error encountered in execution of HPoncfg. Please check the log at program files\hp\hponcfg\ _current_date_time_.txt"

When I go the log I see no data usually. Sometimes I will see a bit of header data where it spells out remote online config utility version and then a line of ======'s for spacing. But that's all that is there.

I never set up a user in lights-out before I hit restart. I have a feeling I somehow locked myself out in doing so. The first couple of launches of the program before I set it from dhcp to static had no issues. As soon as I made the change the error started happening.

Is there anything I can do to reset this or am I going to have to reinstall lights-out? The "reset" options from within Lights-Out both cause an error when I try to run them.

Comment: I keep thinking *"[J-Lo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Lopez)"*

Comment: the dash just adds flair to an otherwise normal acronym.

Answer (score 4):

The ILO configuration can always be overwritten and configured using the BIOS utility. If in doubt, just reboot your server and hit `F8` when prompted in the BIOS to enter the Lights-Out configuration utility. Double-check your settings there.

If you continue to have problems, consider a firmware update. HP has a bootable [Firmware Update DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) that can be used to bring the system inline with reasonable firmware revisions.

Comment: the proliant support pack supposedly pushed an ilo firmware update but I will check into this to make sure it is on the latest rev. Thanks ewwhite

Answer (score 1):

also you may find that this helpful blog;
http://blog.netnerds.net/2006/04/ribcl-reset-administrator-password-on-ilo/
may be of some use
saves you looking in dhcp for the new lease.